# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error in Django sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am working on a script where I created a status model. User can create new status. I have checked the other answers for this but they all seemed code specific.

This is `models.py`:

```
class wall_status(models.Model):
    status = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="custom_student_status",
        default=1, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_status = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='')
```

This is `forms.py`:

```
class statusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    new_status = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta:
        model = wall_status
        fields = ('new_status', )
```

This is my `views.py`:

```
def add_status(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = statusForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('wall')
    else:
        form = statusForm()
    btn = 'Add'
    title = 'Interests'
    return render(request, 'user/profile_info_update.html', {'form': form, 'btn': btn, 
                                                                'title': title})
```

This is template:

```
{% block content %}
          <h2>Sign up</h2>
         <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form.as_p }}
              <button type="submit">{{ btn }}</button>
            </form>
        {% endblock %}
```

Now whats more confusing here is that I was able to add the records in database successfully 5 times and after that it started giving the error. If I manually remove a record and then add from `runserver` again it works but as soon as number of record in table is 5, I get the error. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I still do not understand this if someone does please explain.
So here is what fixed my issue:
I removed this from `models.py`:

```
status = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
```

then when I ran `makemigrations` it asked me to assign a default value to `id`(automatically created primary key i guess).
And then it worked fine. If anyone understands what happened here please explain me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **status** field while saving form which is required as per your model

try this :

```
status = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        blank=True, null=True
    )
```

Comment: no that is automatically added in incremental order.

Comment: thats is all the code. what I am trying to say is that when i add a new record in database its there is a value of status. But after 5 records it started giving the error.